# Searching in table for exact value

Tags: r, count

I have the following table (T1):

```
                                                             verb_object SESSION_ID transactionID sequenceID eventID items
1:     E768D36C813FD14157B06474F345EAFC SELECT;0A5DA9B108F7020C19 SELECT   36652675          2058   36652675       1   OV1
2:                                             0A5DA9B108F7020C19 SELECT   38763251            90   38763251       1   OV2
3: D6941F85A1763F1F2D27B8F032D6411C86D4A5200512D65F381052C7D42BF57F CALL   40257471            63   40257471       1   OV3
4:                                             0A5DA9B108F7020C19 SELECT   40897086         39475   40897086       1   OV1
5: 15873DB37BF80750C70B68A8778B9DC01D548B6D06E3BF92CADAFF289B3FCAEE CALL   40907760            57   40907760       1   OV4
6:                 0A5DA9B108F7020C19 SELECT;E3BF92CADAFF289B3FCAEE CALL   40928334         29697   40928334       1   OV5
```

I would like to count the number of occurrence of the string st in T1$verb_object:

```
0A5DA9B108F7020C19 SELECT
```

The required result would be 2. Since the required string appears as is in lines 2 and 4 only. In lines 1 and 6 it appears as part of string separated by ;.
In addition to the counting is there a way to get the row numbers in which the string was found?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: So, in order to get help, please show what you already tried. The purpose of SO is not to provide ready-to-use code.

Comment: I use the following:
T1[T1[,1]=="0A5DA9B108F7020C19 SELECT"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are looking for an exact string match, you can simply use `==`.

```
x <- T1$verb_object == "0A5DA9B108F7020C19 SELECT"
which(x)
sum(x)
```

`which()` tells you where the matches occur (in this case, the row numbers), and `sum()` tells you how many matches there are in total.

Answer (score 1):

You ma use grep.

```
length(grep("^0A5DA9B108F7020C19 SELECT$", df$verb_object))
```

Comment: Using `^text$` is probably pretty pointless in R. An exact match search using `==` would be quicker and simpler